# C pointers difference between accepting values using arrays and variables?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm new to pointers...

While assigning values to an array using pointer we use:

```
int *arr;
arr = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
   scanf("%d",(arr + i));
}
```

But while assigning to a variable we use

```
int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));
*arr = 10;
```

So why cant we use,

```
scanf("%d",*(arr + i));
```

Why is it showing error?

Comment: I don't see an array here. If a pointer was an array, it would not be called "pointer", but "array" (and vice versa).

Comment: In your last scanf example, you are dereferencing the pointer, whereas scanf expects an address (pointer).

Comment: An array can be a variable.  OP is not using any arrays here.

Comment: You question is confused. See [ask] and provide a [mcve]. Any good C book will give the full picture you apparently don't have. Don't try learning C just by trial-error and from snippets on the internet.

Comment: @Olaf: "*I don't see an array here.*" -- I do. I see an anonymous array object created by the `malloc` call. (Of course `arr` itself is a pointer object, not an array object.)

Comment: Problem: The relationship between arrays and pointers in C can be confusing, and is misunderstood far more than it should be. Solution: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Actually, it is not really confusing. The problem is most teachers don't understand the few rules themselves, less can they teach the complete picture. Instead they concentrate on single aspects. Result is the students also don't abstract and have to start from zero for each variation.

Comment: @Olaf: By "can be confusing", I mean that some people are confused by it. I presume you don't dispute that?

Comment: @KeithThompson: No, I think that's implied by what I wrote in my last comment. And as an "old" Pascal/Modula programmer, I fully agree that the C syntax for declarations does not make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
scanf("%d",(arr + i));
```

`(arr + i)` already is a *pointer* to the i-th element of the array `arr`. Had you `scanf`ed into a "single" variable, you would have had to pass its address (=pointer to that variable).

```
scanf("%d", &some_int_variable);
```

> Why is it showing error?

Dereferencing:

```
scanf("%d",*(arr + i));
```

would be wrong, because it wouldn't pass the pointer to the i-th array member to read to, since `scanf()` **requires** a *pointer* to the argument specified by the *format tag*, not a *value*.

Answer (score 0):

Because `scanf` requires a pointer. Not a value. `*(arr+i)` is the value so if you passed that to `scanf` the function could not change the value so that it was effective after the function call.

It requires a pointer so that it can change the value of the object pointed to and make the change effective after the call.

It is like all function calls in `c`. They pass by value. Inside the function the value may be changed but as soon as the function returns any such changes are lost.

However, if the value passed is the value of a pointer, the function may change the value of the object pointed to by the pointer. Such a change will still be effective when the function returns.

A simple example:

```
void f(int a)
{
    a = 10;  // This change is lost when the function returns
}

void g(int* a)
{
     *a = 10;  // This change will survive when the function returns
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0;
    f(a);
    printf("%d\n", a); // will print 0
    g(&a);
    printf("%d\n", a); // will print 10
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` takes an address (pointer) of a value, the format specifier tells what kind of pointer.

`scanf("%d", (arr + i) )`  means you are giving `scanf` the address `arr` plus an offset of `i`,

when you write `*arr = 10;` you can also write it as `*(arr + 0) = 10;` so you are de-referencing the value and assigning it 10 in other words you cannot give this to `scanf` since it wants a pointer.

so

```
arr = malloc(10*sizeof(int));

      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
arr ->|0  |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   | 9 |
      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

arr + i is an address in the range 0..9, de-referencing a value in the array you write `*(a+i)`

but

```
arr = malloc(sizeof(int));

      +---+
arr ->|   |
      +---+
```

writing `*ar`r you are de-referencing the one value you allocated

```
*arr = 10; 

      +---+
arr ->| 10|
      +---+
```

however writing

```
scanf("%d", arr);
```

is fine since arr is a pointer that points to an integer and scanf takes a pointer.